# How to open pdf file within a web based app using adobe phonegap build

Tags: cordova, pdf, phonegap-build

I have a simple Phonegap Build app where I am loading a websites content and all data and functionality are controlled on the website itself. The app is simply another portal. Is there a way that I would be able to have pdf files load within the app itself on Android as opposed to needing to download the file then view? I have been scouring the forums however they all reference if the pdf file is within the app itself as opposed to on a website the app is loading and am not sure how I would implement this. Any insight would be gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at ***Raymond Camden*** website, he explain how to open an pdf, he use ***cordova-plugin-file-opener2*** plugin :

```
cordova.plugins.fileOpener2.open(
        cordova.file.applicationDirectory+'www/assets/foo.pdf',
        'application/pdf', 
        { 
            error : function(e) { 
                console.log('Error status: ' + e.status + ' - Error message: ' + e.message);
            },
            success : function () {
                console.log('file opened successfully');                
            }
        }
    );
```

**Sources:**

https://www.raymondcamden.com/2016/06/26/linking-to-pdfs-in-cordova-apps
https://github.com/pwlin/cordova-plugin-file-opener2

Comment: this solution uses a local viewer and it seems if the user does not have a viewer installed it returns a error from what the article addresses. The content is being pulled from a WordPress website and at times are within an iframe as well. I am trying to have the pdf content open directly within the app itself as opposed to downloading or using another app to load the pdf file.